# Random ordering of posts on a tumblr site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add to my Tumblr site an additional page that displays all my posts in a random order. Effectively each time this page is loaded or refreshed the posts would be re-ordered randomly. I really want this functionality for my online art and words project as I want people to be able to discover earlier posts in an easy and fun way. I know tumblr already has an inbuilt "/random" feature but this only displays a single post, rather thank randomly ordering *all* posts. For reference my site is [here](http://www.TouchingDoodles.com).

I struggled with some other answers I found on this site as I'm less confident with how exactly to edit and implement changes to my specific themes javascript as opposed to just simply changing the appearance using html and css.

Any help or tips would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Kyle

Comment: What, if anything, have you already tried? If there's anything, please edit your question to include the relevant part of your source, which can lead to an answer.

Comment: Apart from the above, tumblr has no theme operators for `random`: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

Answer (score 0):

You could do a cool trick with jQuery where you load a few posts from the "/random" url and then append them to the current page, using `.load()`.

I tried this by going to "/random" on your page and running the following code. Adds five random posts to the current post list.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    jQuery('.init-posts').append(jQuery('<div>').load('/random .init-posts article'));
}
```

You can apply the same logic to a Custom Page you create so long as it has a template like your single post pages.

Comment: A possible drawback to this approach is that you could get duplicates. You can get around that by checking if the post matches the previous ones, and if it does, get a new random post.